# Forward declare a subclass array

Tags: c++, class, reference, subclass, forward

I understand why this doesn't work as the subclass isn't a forward reference, but is something along these lines with the same theoretical functionality possible?.

This is the implementation I'd use if I could forward reference the subclass array:

class_declare.h:

```
class parentClass{
   int i;
}childClass[100];
```

someSource0.cpp:

```
include "class_declare.h"

//manipulate values of the array - but can this refer to one that is forward declared
//and not a new object?
void dosomething(){
   childclass[1]=10;
}
```

someSource1.cpp:

```
include "class_declare.h"

void dosomethingelse(){
   std::cout<<childclass[1];
}
```

Output:

10

Thank you!.

Comment: There is no subclass here. There's an array of 100 `parentClass`es and it's called "childClass". Perhaps you need [a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: not *forward declare*, but just *declare*: `extern parentClass childclass[100];` in header and `parentClass childclass[100];` in some cpp file

Comment: I understand that I've created an array of the class type, regardless of the mislabeling of the array, I'm wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Thank you Piotr S!. Quick and easy :D. What can I give you in return?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

polymorphism should allow you to create a list of parent objects and populate it with children.

```
class ParentClass{
    int i;
};
ParentClass* ChildClass[100];
```

this declares a list which can contain 100 instances of ParentClass or any of its inheretors.

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/